# how to call a service from one module to another module service in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1. I have a created a service in one module and i am trying to call that service 
   into a another module service .but when i try to call the service function then i am getting a error as method undefined.
   Example Module 1-Service 1 ,Module 2-service 2 I want module 1 service 1

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module("testData", []).service("TestService", function () {

    return {
    
        message: "hai"
    }
})

angular.module("testdata1", ["testData"]).service("TestService1", function (TestService) {

  
    return {

        message: TestService.message
    }
})


angular.module("testData").controller("TestCntrl", function (TestService1,$scope) {

    $scope.test= TestService1.message

})

</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../App/DataAccess/Model.js"></script>
    <script src="../App/DataAccess/Ser.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="testdata1" ng-controller="TestService">

</body>
</html>
```

functions to be  accessed in module 2 service 2.

Answer (score 1):

You've referred to one of your services as a controller for your body tag instead of the controller you defined.

See

```
<body ng-app="testdata1" ng-controller="TestService">
```

Should be

```
<body ng-app="testdata1" ng-controller="TestCntrl">
```

As you defined one controller, **TestCntrl**.

Comment: I corrected it but still.  get the following issue issueReferenceError: TestService is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (HtmlPage.html:34)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4219)
    at extend.instance (angular.js:8516)
    at angular.js:7762
    at forEach (angular.js:334)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7761)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7140)
    at publicLinkFn (angular.js:7019)
    at angular.js:1460
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14570)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependency of module one into second module like this . lets suppose you want to access services of `testData` module in `testData1` then follow the same.

```
angular.module("testData1",['testData']);
```

Comment: I have added the dependency.but still its not working